# joining two tables based on recent logged in datetime

Tags: mysql, join

I am working on `MySql` and have two tables `login_users` and `login_timestamps`

Table `login_users` keeps a record of `user_id`, `name` and `address` whereas table `login_timestamps` keeps a record of `user_id` and `timestamp`, this table adds a new entry each time user logs in, so for example if the `user_id` '1' logs in 10 times a day, this table will have 10 entries for `user_id` '1' for today.

Now I need to fetch user profiles based on their last logged in time.

for example if there are 3 users, the `MySql` query should give me 3 records with their latest logged in time.

The query I am using is

`SELECT * FROM login_users LEFT JOIN login_timestamps ON login_users.user_id = login_timestamps.user_id ORDER BY login_timestamps.timestamp DESC`

but this gives me all the previous logged in entries rather than the recent one only.

Comment: you want get result per day ? today ?

Comment: not per day, one record for each user with their most recent logged in datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you will get all logged in entries while you didnt specify when or what day or something , hete you need a where clause.

try that:

```
  SELECT * FROM login_users 
  LEFT JOIN login_timestamps ON login_users.user_id = login_timestamps.user_id 
  WHERE DATE(`timestamp`) = CURDATE()
  ORDER BY login_timestamps.timestamp DESC
```

this will give you entries for curent day. of course you can specify any condition you want.

EDIT: from your comment.

try that

```
  SELECT l.user_id, max(timestamp)  as lasttime 
  FROM login_users l
  LEFT JOIN login_timestamps lt ON l.user_id = lt.user_id 
  GROUP BY l.user_id
  ORDER BY lasttime DESC
```

Comment: I am trying to now get this data between two date ranges, but this seems to be giving me the data once again of ALL logins between these two dates `SELECT * FROM login_users 
LEFT JOIN login_timestamps ON login_users.user_id = login_timestamps.user_id 
WHERE DATE(login_timestamps.timestamp) BETWEEN '2014-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-03-31 00:00:00'
ORDER BY login_timestamps.timestamp DESC'

Comment: @Baig i dont really catch what you mean, but can you open new question and put your output and wished result. thanks.